# HTML div span two columns and two rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question is really basic I guess but I'm more BE guy so FE is a black magic for me. I've got Ruby on Rails app where front-end part is a standard Rails view (HTML with some ruby part). I want add into existing spanned card additional row to have something like below:

Current view:

```
Issued: test         Expires: 01/01/1900
```

I want add additional line to be:

```
Issued: test         Expires: 01/01/1900
Terminal             Rec Expires: 01/01/2000
```

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
    <span>Issued: test</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <span>Expires: 01/01/1900 %></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
    <span>Terminal</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
    <span>Rec Expires: 01/01/2000</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But instead of expected result I'm getting:

```
Issued: test         Expires: 01/01/1900
Terminal
Rec Expires: 01/01/2000
```

Comment: It appears you are using bootstrap. bootstrap (like most modern U/I frameworks) uses what is called a [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/). Grids have a maximum width (cols) and if you exceed this wrapping will occur.  Bootstrap uses a 12 wide grid so your first 2 divs = 11 (6 +5); however your second 2 divs = 15 (7 +8) since 15 > 12 the wrapping occurs. Basically your divs break out as follows 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 and wrapping occurs every segment in excess of 12 so 5 + 6 | + 7 | +8

Comment: Please tag your bootstrap version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..so you need add row
and fix `col-` classes for 12 columns (look at [engineersmnky comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350541/html-div-span-two-columns-and-two-rows#comment124359299_70350541) )

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
    <span>Issued: test</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
    <span>Expires: 01/01/1900 %></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
    <span>Terminal</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
    <span>Rec Expires: 01/01/2000</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you need equal width of columns, you must set `col-md-6` instead `col-md-5` and `col-md-7` and `col-xs` respectively